# Customize Alfresco Upload Webscript

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I need to customize alfresco upload page , like while importing i want alfreso to prompt for metadata, i knw there are two addon's like uploder + and alvex,but can we create our own ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can customize it.

Basically there are three webscript which are responsible for the uploader in alfresco share.

1. flash-uploader
2. html-uploader
3. dnd-uploader

You can customize flash upload webscript for the same.That is the one which is generally used.dnd upload is for drag and drop.

Webscript Files for the same are as below.

- share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\upload\flash-upload.get.desc.xml
- share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\upload\flash-upload.get.head.ftl
- share\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\upload\flash-upload.get.html.ftl

Client Side dependancies

- share\components\upload\flash-upload.js
- share\components\upload\flash-upload.css

Basically you should extend this webscript.How to extend the webscript component is very well explained in below link.

http://soft29.info/blog/entry/alfresco-extend-share-javascript-component

after extending it you can give reference of the new component in below file.

- file-upload.get.html.ftl